# Repartitioning Lenovo laptop HDD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, boot-partition

I've recently purchased a Lenovo B570 laptop and decided that I'd like to repartition it.
So I created a Windows disk image using the built in feature and booted the device using an Ubuntu live USB disk.

But after I checked the current partition scheme I noticed there are 2 hidden partitions. One is 200 MB and contains the boot data (e.g. `bootmgr`, etc.) the other is 15 GB and after mounting it there was again the boot data and some other data such as `OneKeyRecovery` backup files, a folder named `Factory_Process` and etc.

Now I'm having second thoughts. What should I do here? I'd very much like to delete everything and start fresh. But would I lose some critical material which is needed for the proper functioning of the device?
Any help and insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the 15 gb partition a recovery partition that contains a full setup of the original OS?

Comment: I suspect it is. With all the needed drivers.

Comment: Ok, so is this the case for you: "Near to the power button there should be another button with a curved arrow.
Press this button to start Lenovo OneKey Recovery to boot into the reserve recovery partition.
When boot is complete, follow the onscreen instruction when you need to restore the drive to factory default."

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Comment: Are you planning to install the same/original OS that came with your laptop? If so, there is no need to remove the partition(s). You could use the recovery partition to reinstall your OS. It should give you the option to reformat the drive (and thus, start with a clean install). I don't think you need the 15 gb that much, right? Also, the 2 partitions should not affect the behavior of your computer in general.

Comment: Nope, I don't want the original OS (since it's Win7 Home Basic and way too limited for my needs). I plan to install Win8. For the record I have already made a back up of all the mentioned data on an external HDD. So you say I can erase everything with clear conscience?

Comment: I believe you can remove the recovery partition. If I am not mistaking there should even be a tool for that from lenovo. There is also the option to create (a) recovery disc(s). This may be unnecessary if you are not going to use the old OS, but might relax your mind. This is also pretty much what is written here: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-Tablet-ThinkPad-Laptops/Recovery-partition-delete-after-making-recover-dsks/td-p/660751

Comment: Ok thanks. Would you please sum up your information in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 15 gb. partition is a recovery partition, you might want to keep it if you would like to reinstall your OS. You may be able to create recovery disc(s) so that you can keep the option of restoring your OS, but also are able to remove the recovery partition.

You can access the recovery with the 'curved arrow' button on the side of your laptop (the One Key Recovery button).

The Service Partition (the partition without a drive letter) is used by the OneKey recovery system to backup and recover the C partition. This invisible partition requires only 18GB to 20GB of HDD space. The service partition should NOT be deleted otherwise your OneKey recovery will no longer operate.
One advantage of having these partitions is the protection of your personal data. In the event you need to use the OneKey recovery system, the personal data stored on the D drive will not be erased as the files on the C drive are restored (http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/Disk-Partitioning-and-OneKey-Recovery-Feature/td-p/8036)

So if you really do not care about the older OS, and would like to have that extra ~15gb of space, you could repartition and reformat your drive (http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-Tablet-ThinkPad-Laptops/Recovery-partition-delete-after-making-recover-dsks/td-p/660751).